# Form does not require empty fields

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that all fields are set to required. When I press the save button, it saves the input values into local storage. But Save button still saves even though there are empty fields.
Here is the code:

```
<form class="column-full item" id="input-form">
            <label for="image-url" required >Image URL: </label><br>
            <input oninput="loadImage()"  class="row" type="text" id="image-url" placeholder="Type the URL of your image" required /><br>
            <label for="image-title">Title: </label><br>
            <input class="row" type="text" id="image-title" required /><br>
            <label for="image-details">Notes: </label><br>
            <input class="row" type="text" id="image-details" required /><br>
            <button onclick="saveInput()" class="row" type="submit" value="Save" id="btn_save">Save</button>
</form>

<script>
let journalPages = [];
    function saveInput(events){
      let newPage={
        id: Date.now(),
        imageURL: document.getElementById('image-url').value,
        imageTitle: document.getElementById('image-title').value,
        imageDetails: document.getElementById('image-details').value
      }
      
      journalPages.push(newPage);               //Add the new entry object to the array
      document.querySelector('form').reset();   //Clear the form

      console.warn('added', {journalPages});

      localStorage.setItem('MyPage', JSON.stringify(journalPages));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you'r listening for any click event on your form button, so when the click happens your function `saveInputs` will be called.

Here is what you should do:

- Remove the `onclick` event from the `button` element
- Add the `onsubmit="saveInput()"` to your `form` element

This way the `savedInput` function will only be called when the form is able to be submitted (all fields filled and matching the rules)

```html
<form onsubmit="saveInput()" class="column-full item" id="input-form">
            <label for="image-url" required >Image URL: </label><br>
            <input oninput="loadImage()"  class="row" type="text" id="image-url" placeholder="Type the URL of your image" required /><br>
            <label for="image-title">Title: </label><br>
            <input class="row" type="text" id="image-title" required /><br>
            <label for="image-details">Notes: </label><br>
            <input class="row" type="text" id="image-details" required /><br>
            <button class="row" type="submit" value="Save" id="btn_save">Save</button>
</form>
```

```js
let journalPages = [];
function saveInput(events){
  let newPage={
    id: Date.now(),
    imageURL: document.getElementById('image-url').value,
    imageTitle: document.getElementById('image-title').value,
    imageDetails: document.getElementById('image-details').value
  }

  journalPages.push(newPage); //Add the new entry object to the array
  document.querySelector('form').reset();   //Clear the form

  console.warn('added', {journalPages});

  localStorage.setItem('MyPage', JSON.stringify(journalPages));
};
```

Here is the jsfiddle of your code working as intended: https://jsfiddle.net/emycrzbk/1/

Comment: That worked for required field wise. But now when I click save with all fields complete, it saves the input for a moment, then it disappears. So, it does not add the new object to the array. The object disappears right at the moment it saves. It never makes an array of objects.

Comment: I think this happens because the page loads when you submit the form, so the variable resets?! This isn't part of the question so i didn't notice that. But here it goes: You can use `event.preventDefault();` inside your function to prevent the form from submitting, or you can get the `journalPages` items from `localStorage` at begging of the function `journalPages = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('MyPage')) || [];` .

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/64ko2n3L/7/

Comment: Dont forget to pass the `event` variable on html tag `onsubmit="saveInput(event)` and get it on your function args `function saveInput(event)`